Receptacle Boxes
I had a contractor do some remodeling for me. He had an Electrian install boxes in the ceiling supposedly for flush mount led lighting. I let the contractor go over some other issues. I looked at the ceiling they had installed rectangle receptacle boxes. What led lighting should work on those since not actual J boxes? I am confused.

It seems weird, but talk to contractor/electrician, maybe they have lights that fit, or one goofed up.  LEDs are not limited to certain shapes.

....the NEC doesn't treat junction boxes differently based on whether they're rectangular or not -- it's simply that some fixtures don't have mounting points suitable for hanging them from a rectangular gang box in the ceiling.  Anyway, what make/model of LED fixtures were you after?
